# Convert Material UI app to mobile and make it responsive

Tags: reactjs, responsive-design, material-ui

I was building a web app with React and Material UI and I have difficulty with mobile size. So I have several questions:

1. How to make margins responsive for example:  `marginLeft: theme.spacing(20),` this is how I set up margin for logo  **example on desktop:**[image] 
   **example mobile:** 
   [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [CSS Media Queries](https://material-ui.com/customization/breakpoints/#css-media-queries):

> CSS media queries are the idiomatic approach to make your UI
> responsive. The theme provides four styles helpers to do so:
>
> - theme.breakpoints.up(key)
> - theme.breakpoints.down(key)
> - theme.breakpoints.only(key)
> - theme.breakpoints.between(start, end)

**Default breakpoints:**

> Each breakpoint (a key) matches with a fixed screen width (a value):
>
> - **xs**, extra-small: 0px
> - **sm**, small: 600px
> - **md**, medium: 960px
> - **lg**, large: 1280px
> - **xl**, extra-large: 1920px
>
> These breakpoint values are used to determine breakpoint ranges. A
> range starts from the breakpoint value inclusive, to the next
> breakpoint value exclusive:
>
> ```
> value         |0px     600px    960px    1280px   1920px  
> key           |xs      sm       md       lg       xl   
> screen width  |--------|--------|--------|--------|-------->  
> range         |   xs   |   sm   |   md   |   lg   |   xl
> ```
>
> These values can be [customized](https://material-ui.com/customization/breakpoints/#custom-breakpoints).

Example:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  myLogo: {
    // Match [md, ∞)
    //       [960px, ∞)
    [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
      ...,
      marginLeft: theme.spacing(20),
      ...
    },
    // Match [0, sm + 1)
    //       [0, md)
    //       [0, 960px[
    [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
      ...,
      // no margin
    },
  }
}));
```

Comment: It says, I can accept answer after 18 hours*

Comment: Also quick question, someone suggested using `Box`, is it make the page more responsive?

Comment: Do you mean [`Grid`](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/) ?

Comment: I mean this - https://material-ui.com/components/box/ does it help to page responsive?

Comment: No, but for the `Grid` yes

Comment: Great, got it, thank you very much. I will release the bounty as soon as possible.

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 2):

I once had a similar problem in a project I was doing. I solved with [react-device-detect](https://github.com/duskload/react-device-detect). With this package you can set margin and layout in general based on device running your app.

```
import {
  BrowserView,
  MobileView,
  isBrowser,
  isMobile
} from "react-device-detect";
```

Then you can both generate two views

```
<BrowserView>
    <h1> This is rendered only in browser </h1>
</BrowserView>
<MobileView>
    <h1> This is rendered only on mobile </h1>
</MobileView>
```

Or use `isMobile` for conditional rendering.